# Are there prior examples when a US president was strongly at odds with the grassroots of his party over a foreign policy issue?

Tags: united-states, history, foreign-policy, comparative-politics, grassroots

Quincy Institute for Responsible Statecraft, [Nov 15](https://responsiblestatecraft.org/public-supports-ceasefire-gaza/):

> More than two-thirds of Americans support a ceasefire in Israel’s war on Gaza, according to a Reuters/Ipsos poll whose results were released on Wednesday. The poll, which gathered responses from just over 1,000 respondents earlier this week, also shows that U.S. support for Israel has declined in the month since Hamas’s incursion into Israel on October 7. The percentage of respondents who said that "the U.S. should support Israel" when asked what role Washington should play in the war dropped from 41% in mid-October to 32% percent this week.
>
> The 68% of respondents who agreed with the statement, “Israel should call a ceasefire and try to negotiate," were divided by political party, with approximately 75% of Democrats and about half of Republicans concurring.
>
> The overwhelming support from Democratic respondents puts them squarely at odds with the party’s political leadership in Washington.  President Joe Biden said last week that there was “no possibility” of a ceasefire in Gaza, and only 27 congressional Democrats (about 10% of the conference) have publicly supported one.

So, are there prior examples when the grassroots of one party and their elected representatives (POTUS included) disagreed strongly over a foreign policy issue?

Comment: Thing is that the Gaza issue only looks really "hot" right now.  Give it 3 months past a ceasefire and no one will remember that Israel has been shirking on Oslo and UN 242 for decades.  So this is only temporarily "unprecedented" and you could probably look at numerous *temporary* spikes in dissent, asides from the ones cited above that people remember about.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: I'm fine with answers providing more depth on past issues such as *temporary* disagreements, followed by the grassroots "seeing the light" thanks to enlightened leadership.

Comment: All of them? A grassroots movement would not exist if politicians did what their local communities wanted. Unless you mean something different by "grassroots"?

Comment: @uberhaxed: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grassroots "the ordinary people in a society or an organization, especially a political party". It doesn't necessarily imply disagreement, although I'd grant you that when people use that word, they often use it when there is one, at least of nuance. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grassroots "the basic level of society or of an organization especially as viewed in relation to higher or more centralized positions of power"